# uploading csv file to mysql with one column containing text wilth multiple lines and " and ,

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I'm having a problem uploading my data to my mysql data base.

The data looks something like this:

review_id,user,text

And a typical row looks like this:

```
12345,SomeCoolName,"this is my "awsome" comment.
some more text, and dome more.
and some "more""
```

This should be one row in my table.

I'm having problem uploading this because of the multiple lines and use of commas and paranteses in the text field.
Any suggestions on how i can handle this?

Thanks!

I've tried using some manuals I found on uploading csv files to data base but wasn't successful.

Comment: String literals should be delimited with single quotes `'this "text" will work'`; if you have single quotes then escape them `''`

Comment: the text can be full of " and ,
this is from a dataset downloaded, i need to escape every single quote inside the text and that should fix it?

Comment: *This should be one row in my table* How to define where one row finishes and another one starts? PS. Multiline and quote chars presence is not a problem. PPS. What is MySQl version precisely?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out. The text part should be one field in a row of data in the database

Comment: Your CSV contains the data for only one row?

Comment: no, i have around 5m lines total, that would be around 20K rows in the table

Comment: Provide: complete CREATE TABLE for destination table; a sample of CSV file content which contains the data for 3 destination rows (mark EOL with <EOL>); desired final destination table's data state after importing for shown source sample data.

Answer (score 0):

### DEMO sample.

Source CSV content which must be imported:

```
review_id,user,text
123,John,This is
multiline 1, which
contains a comma.
456,Jim,This is
miltiline 2, which contains
commas, 'quote' chars and "double quote" chars.
```

The table which this data must be imported into:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (review_id INT, user VARCHAR(255), review_text TEXT);
```

The query which loads the data into the table:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/test.csv'
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\0' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@line)
SET review_id = (@review_id := CASE WHEN @line REGEXP '^\\d'
                                    THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(@line, ',', 1)
                                    ELSE @review_id
                                    END
                                    ),
    user =  (@user := CASE WHEN @line REGEXP '^\\d'
                           THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@line, ',', 2), ',', -1)
                           ELSE @user
                           END
                           ),
    review_text = (@review_text := CASE WHEN @line REGEXP '^\\d'
                                        THEN SUBSTRING(@line FROM 2 + LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@line, ',', 2)))
                                        ELSE CONCAT_WS(' ', @review_text, @line)
                                        END
                                        );
```

The table data state immediately after loading:

| review_id | user | review_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | This is |
| 123 | John | This is multiline 1, which |
| 123 | John | This is multiline 1, which contains a comma. |
| 456 | Jim | This is |
| 456 | Jim | This is miltiline 2, which contains |
| 456 | Jim | This is miltiline 2, which contains commas, 'quote' chars and "double quote" chars. |

Clearing:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 USING (user)
WHERE t1.review_text < t2.review_text;
```

Final table data state:

| review_id | user | review_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | This is multiline 1, which contains a comma. |
| 456 | Jim | This is miltiline 2, which contains commas, 'quote' chars and "double quote" chars. |

Comment: Thank you so much Akina! sorry for the delay, had some unexpected events.
I'll try your solution!, thanks